# oracle exception handling when others

Tags: oracle, exception

In my below block i cant get executed exception when others  in any manner .Is there any syntax error?? Also i cant call the procedure inside exception.Any solution??

```
DECLARE  
  CNT INT;  
  err_msg VARCHAR2(2000);    
BEGIN  
  SELECT av_isdbcexecuted(1, 'DDL') INTO CNT FROM DUAL;  
  IF (CNT = 0) THEN  
    BEGIN  
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('INSIDE IF...');  
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'call AV_DBCINSERT  
 (1,''DDL'',''hsolanki'',''Prj1'',''Item1'',''avarne'')';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE AV_TEMP (col1 varchar(20))';     
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        --inside exception
        err_msg := sqlerrm;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('INSIDE exception...' || err_msg);  
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'call AV_DBCUPDATE (1,err_msg,''Failed'')';            
    END;  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'call AV_DBCUPDATE(1, NULL,''SUCCESS'')';  
  END IF;  
END;
```

Comment: thanks for editing

Comment: I think you `don't need` to do `execute immediate call` for all your procedures. Simply put the procedure calls without execute immediate. Do like- `AV_DBCINSERT(1,'DDL','hsolanki','Prj1','Item1','avarne');` `AV_DBCUPDATE (1,err_msg,'Failed');` and  `AV_DBCUPDATE(1, NULL,'SUCCESS');`

Comment: thanks @KeyurPanchal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line isn't correct:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'call AV_DBCUPDATE (1,err_msg,''Failed'')';
```

Your should allow `err_msg`  to be evaluated!

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'call AV_DBCUPDATE (1,'''||err_msg||''',''Failed'')';
```

Then, [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](http://psoug.org/definition.htm/EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE.htm)  is not designed to do what you intend to do.

Here is the way you must proceed to be simple:

```
DECLARE  
  CNT INT;  
  err_msg VARCHAR2(2000);    
BEGIN  
  SELECT av_isdbcexecuted(1, 'DDL') INTO CNT FROM DUAL;  
  IF (CNT = 0) THEN  
    BEGIN  
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('INSIDE IF...');  
      AV_DBCINSERT (1,'DDL','hsolanki','Prj1','Item1','avarne');
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE AV_TEMP (col1 varchar(20))';     
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        --inside exception
        err_msg := sqlerrm;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('INSIDE exception...' || err_msg);  
        AV_DBCUPDATE (1,err_msg,'Failed');            
    END;  
    AV_DBCUPDATE(1, NULL,'SUCCESS')';  
  END IF;  
END;
```